# Changing a stylesheet through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the stylesheet of my page through a javascript function. It does work at first, but after 2 clicks the variable defining the non-active stylesheet gets stuck on the "dark" value.

I would be very grateful if I received support from this amazing community. ^^

Here you have both the page and the source code:

**Link:** https://jadeblink.netlify.app

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title>JADEblink*</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="pagestyle" href="dark.css">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" id="pagestyle" href="light.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pagetitle">
        JADE<span id="blink">blink*</span>
        <div class="shape" onclick="changeStyle();">Change to<br><span id="xstyle"></span> style<div>
        <script>
            var t=setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("xstyle").innerHTML=otherstyle;},100);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var otherstyle="light";
function changeStyle() {
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', otherstyle+".css");
    if(otherstyle="dark")
        otherstyle="light";
    if(otherstyle="light")
        otherstyle="dark";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's something wrong in your logic.

Using `if(otherstyle="dark")` won't compare it, as you need to use `==` to compare, or `===` for a strict comparison.

Apart from that, if you're setting it to `light`, it will enter your next `if` condition, restoring it to `dark`, so you need to use an `else if` for the second condition.

This should do the trick:

```
var otherstyle = "light";

function changeStyle() {
  document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', otherstyle + ".css");
  if (otherstyle == "dark")
    otherstyle = "light";
  else if (otherstyle == "light")
    otherstyle = "dark";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I am actually embarrassed of the error I've committed by not using else and not realizing it. Kind thoughts <3